# How do I access /db (Heroku PHP documentation)

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, heroku, pdo

In the Heroku PHP documentation they talk about "accessing /db" but I am not sure how to do this. Here is the page I am referring to:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-php#provision-a-database

It's the part that starts "Now when you access your app’s /db route..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/db` will be exposed as a web page and will return the contents defined by the query and the template. This way you can easily provide read access (`GET` http method) for a table's content.

Answer (score 1):

As a total newbie to PHP and heroku, I had this same question. After some playing around I found that "when you access your app’s /db route" means to do the same thing as you did for the cowsay dependency earlier in the tutorial but replace 'cowsay' with 'db', so

instead of:

```
$ heroku open cowsay
```

write

```
$ heroku open db
```